# Store List in JPA without an annotation

Tags: java, jpa

I have this entity for example:

```
public class MessageComment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String creator;

    private List<OtherComments> otherComments = new ArrayList<OtherComments>();

}
```

In this code notwhing is annotated with OneToMany and Column or nothing else. I´m not sure how JPA will store this case in the database. How can help me?

```
 private List<OtherComments> otherComments = new ArrayList<OtherComments>();
```

Thanks a lot!
Maik

Answer (score 0):

JPA class is simply a class used for for *Object to Relational Mapping*, once the class is a `JPA` ,every member in it, is by default a part of **Java Persistence Architecture ** .

Thus you can't create a set of variables in it, if you are creating a variable inside the JPA you must specify that the variable so created is not a part of any database relations.

Which you can do by using `@Transient`, this annotations will be used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database.

Comment: does not answer the question, As far as I understood it, the OP wants to persist the list in the DB simply as a List , which IMHO is not possible

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I think answered to the point. As far as i understood he asked, when a List is not annotated, then what will happen. !!

Answer (score 0):

The `List<OtherComments> otherComments` is a *collection-valued* field and the database model depends on the type of column in the list:

1. If the list's column is of type ***Basic*** then provider will create

   - *collection table* with name defaulted to `MESSAGECOMMENT_OTHERCOMMENTS` containing

     - the foreign key column related to `MESSAGECOMMENT` table
     - the column related to the given basic type
2. If the list's column is of type ***Embeddable*** then provider will create

   - *collection table* with name defaulted to `MESSAGECOMMENT_OTHERCOMMENTS` containing

     - the foreign key column related to `MESSAGECOMMENT` table
     - the columns related to the embeddable's fields
3. If the list's column is of type ***Entity*** then provider will create

   - additional table with name defaulted to `OTHERCOMMENTS` containing

     - the columns related to the given entity type
   - *join table* with name defaulted to `MESSAGECOMMENT_OTHERCOMMENTS` containing

     - the foreign key columns of `MESSAGECOMMENT` and `OTHERCOMMENTS` tables

I hope it helps.